# How to use VSCode to debug C++ code in ubuntu with gdb and shell script

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, gdb, vscode-debugger

The project has `CMakeLists.txt` (`codes` folder), and have multiple subdirectories, each having separate `CMakeLists.txt`. Started to use VSCode. Build process I got working. Now, moving forward I am stuck in debugging process using VSCode.

I open VSCode with the `codes` folder (from here I run Build). The files I edit in `mainFolder/codes/projectA/mySubProj/*.*`.

Normally debug process is I open terminal and go to `mainFolder/qa/scripts/` folder and run `sh project.sh -u /inputDirFullPath/`. The related shell scripts contents are as follows:

mainFolder/qa/scripts/project.sh:

```
<several shell commands>
myProj.sh -f filePath1 -h filePath2 -o dirName
<several other shell commands>
```

mainFolder/qa/scripts/mySubProj.sh

```
gdb --args mySubProj $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6
<some other shell commands>
```

Now, my question is how to set this up in VSCode? Any help?

Edit 1:
Got it working, help from [this page](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cmake-tools/blob/develop/docs/debug-launch.md).

Comment: Just follow one of these tutorials. 
[official](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/launch-json-reference)
[gourav](https://gourav.io/blog/setup-vscode-to-run-debug-c-cpp-code)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I have installed extensions (C++ Extension Pack by Microsoft). I also auto-generated launch.json and tasks.json files. The main problem is what to edit in launch.json to invoke the existing script(s) and the debug.

Comment: You need to edit gdb path (miDebuggerPath) and your program executable.

"program": "${workspaceFolder}/a.out",
"linux": {
    "MIMode": "gdb",
    "miDebuggerPath": "/usr/bin/gdb"
  },